# how to segregate a comma separated multivalued DN String to array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I segregate a comma separated multivalued DN String to array using JavaScript/jQuery? (e.g. String is: `cn=stanley01,ou=employee,o=user,cn=martha,ou=employee,o=user,cn=asley,ou=employee,o=user)`

Comment: [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Guys, Sorry!! I think this word "DN" has created a confusion. Actually, I have the string cn=stanley01,ou=employee,o=user,cn=martha,ou=employee,o=user,cn=asley,ou=employee,o=user in my variable. when I am trying split on basis of comma things are getting in array as ["cn=Stanley","ou=employee","o=user",.....and so on]...but I need result as ["cn=stanley01,ou=employee,o=user","cn=martha,ou=employee,o=user","cn=asley,ou=employee,o=user"] so now, is there any way out? I am sorry, as for understanding purpose only I placed the word DN in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()`, `slice()` & `join()`. Example:

```
var str = 'cn=stanley01,ou=employee,o=user,cn=martha,ou=employee,o=user,cn=asley,ou=employee,o=user';
var arr = str.split(','),
    newArr = [],
    final_array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=3){
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+3));
}
newArr.map(function(val, key){
    final_array.push(val.join());
});
console.log(final_array);
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Use split() function

```
var strdata = cn=stanley01,ou=employee,o=user,cn=martha,ou=employee,o=user,cn=asley,ou=employee,o=user;
var arraydata = strdata.split(",");
```

Comment: How is this different from the existing answer? Other than being syntactically invalid, that is.

Comment: Cool Raoul - I just answered the same time - nobody's perfect

Comment: What? No, you posted several minutes later. Your answer is still wrong though. Try it.